# Django RawQuerySet Subtraction with raw query

Tags: django, orm

I'm trying this query in postgres it working

```
select
  (SELECT sum(amount)
   FROM expense_expense
   WHERE flow='INFLOW')-
  (SELECT sum(amount)
   FROM expense_expense
   WHERE flow='OUTFLOW') AS balance;
```

Getting Out Put

```
balance|
-------|
6370.77|
```

But when i try with Django RawQuerySet It is asking for primary key

```
In [168]: r = Expense.objects.raw("select(select sum(amount) FROM expense_expense  where flow='INFLOW') - (select sum(amount) FROM expense_expense  where flow='OUTFLOW') as balance;")                                                          

In [169]: r.columns                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[169]: ['balance']

In [170]: r[0]                                                                    

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidQuery                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-170-8418cdc095ae> in <module>
----> 1 r[0]

~/Desktop/workspace/projects/python/django/expenditure/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __getitem__(self, k)
   1433 
   1434     def __getitem__(self, k):
-> 1435         return list(self)[k]
   1436 
   1437     @property

~/Desktop/workspace/projects/python/django/expenditure/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__(self)
   1393 
   1394     def __iter__(self):
-> 1395         self._fetch_all()
   1396         return iter(self._result_cache)
   1397 

~/Desktop/workspace/projects/python/django/expenditure/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _fetch_all(self)
   1380     def _fetch_all(self):
   1381         if self._result_cache is None:
-> 1382             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
   1383         if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
   1384             self._prefetch_related_objects()

~/Desktop/workspace/projects/python/django/expenditure/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in iterator(self)
   1408             model_init_names, model_init_pos, annotation_fields = self.resolve_model_init_order()
   1409             if self.model._meta.pk.attname not in model_init_names:
-> 1410                 raise InvalidQuery('Raw query must include the primary key')
   1411             model_cls = self.model
   1412             fields = [self.model_fields.get(c) for c in self.columns]

InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key

In [171]:
```

Is there anything I'm missing or anything I need to do, please let me know how can I achieve this. It will be very help full for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Django aims to parse the result to an `Expense` object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for your reply .So how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use raw queries for such aggregates, since [**`.raw(..)`** queries [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) are used to retrieve model objects:

> The `raw()` manager method can be used to perform raw SQL queries that **return model instances**.

But it is simply not necessary to use a raw query in the first place. You should in fact avoid that unless there are no reasonable options to use the ORM instead.

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

Expense.objects.aggregate(
    balance=Sum('amount', filter=Q(flow='INFLOW'))-Sum('amount', filter=Q(flow='OUTFLOW'))
)
```

this returns a dictionary with a key named `'balance'` that maps to the balance.

If there are more flows than only `'INFLOW'` and `'OUTFLOW'`, you can slightly boost performance by first filtering the queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

Expense.objects.filter(
    flow__in=('INFLOW', 'OUTFLOW')
).aggregate(
    balance=Sum('amount', filter=Q(flow='INFLOW'))-Sum('amount', filter=Q(flow='OUTFLOW'))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I tried this orm got the result value as {'balance': Decimal('0.00')}

Comment: @AjayKumar: yes, I used `INFLOW` two times :)